# What should I take Live Load and Sustained Dead Load for Parking and Technical Floors?

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering

I have a residential Tower (36 story) and i want to find the design loads (Live Loads and Sustained Dead Loads in t/m<sup>2</sup>) for Technical and Parking floors.

I am currently using the ASCE (Table 4-1 Minimum Uniformly Distributed Live Loads, Lo, and Minimum Concentrated Live Loads) as a reference to find the loads for the typical floors but it doesn't refer to either technical Floors nor Parking.

If anyone know any reference that I could use to find these loads I would appreciate it.

Comment: I've never heard of a "technical floor". For parking - you could try finding the weight of a car and divide it by it's plan area to get an estimate. Or you could try and find highway loading specs, but these are more likely to assume back-to-back trucks (which I assume can't get into your parking floor due to head clearance issues).

Comment: The technical Floor is for the Residential Floors, but i need both the live load for parking and live load for the Technical Floor.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a Technical Floor but in Table 4-1 see the section 'Residential' for residential floor loads. Also see the section 'Garages (passenger vehicles only)' for the parking floor loads.